# Recurrence relation for the number of strings of length $n$ over the alphabet $\{1, 2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ such that there are no consecutive $1$'s or $2$'s.

Tags: combinatorics

Find a recurrence relation for the number of strings of length $n$ over the alphabet $\{1, 2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ such that there are no consecutive $1$'s or $2$'s.

I have no idea where to start. I've been stuck for some time. Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: How can there be consecutive $0$s if there are no $0$s.

Comment: oops, changed $0$'s to $2$'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on Ross's hint.

Let $a_n$ be the number of good strings of length $n$

Let $b_n$ be the number of good strings of length $n$ which do not end in a $1$ or $2$

Let $c_n$ be the number of good strings of length $n$ which end in $1$

Let $d_n$ be the number of good strings of length $n$ which end in $2$

This gives the recurrence $a_n=b_n+c_n+d_n$

Obviously, $b_n = 5a_{n-1}$

Also we have $c_n=b_{n-1}+d_{n-1}$ because the right hand side of the equation is the number of good strings of length $n-1$ which do not end in a $1$.

Finally, $d_n=b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}$ because the right hand side of the equation is the number of good strings of length $n-1$ which do not end in a $2$

Substituting for $b_n$, $c_n$, $d_n$ in the first equation the equations we get, $a_n = 5a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}+d_{n-1}+b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}$ = $5a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}+a_{n-1}$ =  $6a_{n-1}+5a_{n-2}$

Therefore, $a_n=6a_{n-1}+5a_{n-2}$

Answer (score 5):

Make coupled recurrences, one for the number of good strings of length $n$ that do not end in $1$ or $2$ and one for the number of good strings that do end in $1$ or $2$.  Given the number of each, how many strings of length $n+1$ of each type are there?

Answer (score 1):

Strings of length $n\ge 2$ fall in two classes; those that end with a double letter, and those that do not. There are $6a_{n-1}$  strings which do not end with a double letter (six choices for the end letter, anything but the previous), and $5a_{n-2}$ which do (five choices for the double, anything but $11$ or $22$), so
$$
a_{n}=6a_{n-1}+5a_{n-2},\qquad n\ge2.
$$

Comment: Very neat but I think...  while deleting $22$ does leave a legal string of length $n-1$, it doesn't leave all possible legal strings of length $n-1$, namely, it doesn't leave legal strings of length $n-1$ which end in $2$.  A pity if I'm right though, as this is much neater than Ross's standard solution.

Comment: antkam, while Ross's solution is very neat, i think you're right.

Comment: @antkam Yep, I was way off! Oh well, with the hind sight of Adi's answer, I can now give a nice combinatorial proof of the recursion.

Comment: Great!  It often (always?) happens that a set of coupled recurrences can be reduced to only 1 recurrence of the main series.  I've often wondered if the single recurrence can then be "retroactively" explained -- it's lovely that you found the way in this case.  If you have "general techniques" to share, I'd love to hear them.  :)

Comment: @antkam No general techniques yet, though I certainly want to know them and thing they must exist. BTW, the answer to your "always?" question is yes. Any system of recurrences can be described by a vector-matrix recurrence ${\bf v}_{n+1}=A{\bf v}_n$. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ gives a univariate recurrence solved by each coordinate of ${\bf v}_n$, allowing you to decouple.