# Find a recurrence relation and give initial conditions for the number of words of length $n$ that do not contain two consecutive vowels.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, combinatorics-on-words

I'm trying to find a recurrence relation for the number of words of length $n$ that do NOT contain two consecutive vowels.

I'm trying to relate the problem to a similar one, of bit strings (Say, a relation for the number of bit strings that do not contain four consecutive 0's), but I'm starting to think I don't understand that either.

My though process:

Assume $a_n $ represents the number of words that do not contain consecutive vowels.
If there are 26 letters in the English alphabet and 5 vowels (not including the letter "y"), then there are $26^n$ total words. When researching online, I find that similar problems lead people to using $a_{n-1}$, but I don't understand where that comes from. Can anyone offer me some insight? Thank you.

Comment: Oops, typo. Thank you.

Comment: You could look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3147333/recurrence-relation-for-the-number-of-strings-of-length-n-over-the-alphabet), which is the same except for the number of characters in each group.

Answer (score 1):

Think as follows: A sequence of length $n$ that doesn't end in a vowel can be followed by a non-vowel or a vowel followed by a non-vowel. This gives a recurrence (How many of those are of length 0? 1?). Solve that one, and consider the case where it ends in vowel.